# Scrape with wildcards and php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, parsing, screen-scraping

I have a hard time visualizing and conceiving away to scrape this page: http://www.morewords.com/ends-with/aw for the words themselves. Given a URL, I'd like to get the contents and then generate a php array with all the words listed, which in the source look like

```
<a href="/word/word1/">word1</a><br />
<a href="/word/word2/">word2</a><br />
<a href="/word/word3/">word3</a><br />
<a href="/word/word4/">word4</a><br />
```

There are a few ways I have been thinking about doing this, i'd appreciate if you could help me decide the most efficient way. Also, i'd appreciate any advice or examples on how to achieve this. I understand it's not incredibly complicated, but I could use the help of you advanced hackers.

- Use some sort of jquery `$.each()` to loop through and somehow case them into a JS array, and then transcribe (probably heavily taxing)
- use some sort of curl (don't really have much experience with curl)
- use some sophisticated find and replace with regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You tagged it as PHP, so here is a PHP solution :)

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;

$dom->loadHTMLFile('http://www.morewords.com/ends-with/aw');

$anchors = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');

$words = array();

foreach($anchors as $anchor) {
    if ($anchor->hasAttribute('href') AND preg_match('~/word/\w+/~', $anchor->getAttribute('href'))) {
        $words[] = $anchor->nodeValue;
    }
}
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/UOXfuN).

If [`allow_url_fopen`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) is disabled in `php.ini`, you could use cURL to get the HTML.

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.morewords.com/ends-with/aw'); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$html = curl_exec($curl);    
curl_close($curl);
```

Comment: it really looks like it should work, and on your example, it does! However, it does not on my host for some reason: http://go.phpfogapp.com/ here is the code: http://gist.github.com/da32674c011d51503453

Comment: @willum To open the URL like that, you probably need `allow_url_fopen` on in `php.ini`. If you have it disabled, you could use the cURL library to pass the HTML to `DOMDocument`.

Comment: also, i'd love for the solution to be in PHP, if possible.

Comment: @willum The example above *is* PHP. If you were referring to the cURL library, PHP has functions to interact with it directly from PHP.

Comment: can you show me how I would use curl to route it through? PHPFog, my host, isn't flexible with changing php.ini.

Comment: Yes, I know it is alex :) I'm just responding to "You tagged it as PHP, so here is a PHP solution :)"

Comment: @willum This [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) has everything you need. To see if you have [`allow_url_fopen`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) on, check `phpinfo()`.

Comment: I have it off, I checked. I was asking on the details of a work around, I don't have much experience with curl.

Comment: can you do stuff like "getElementsByTagName" in curl?

Comment: I'm lost, I'm trying to figure out curl with the docs, but I don't get how I can use it. Its impossible to enable allow_url_fopen

Comment: @willum cURL is a library for playing with HTTP and URLs. You'd get the HTML via cURL, and then pass it to DOMDocument. Once the HTML is passed, cURL has done its job.

Comment: great, can you show me the function to pass curl to Dom? this: http://gist.github.com/32b368e6586b5d5e5c9d doesn't seem to work

Comment: ok, well. Here is my current code: http://gist.github.com/48295ca2d7cab034c236 hm... the site is blank.

Comment: @willum You should turn error reporting on and you forgot to instantiate the `DOMDocument` class.

Comment: It changed to array(0) { } as the output. What exactly does that mean, you think? I initialized the dom, I accidentally deleted it earlier, sorry.

Comment: tbh I think $anchors is empty.

Comment: @willum Replace `loadHTMLFile()` with `loadHTML()`. [CodePad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/4hH7x4).

Comment: @willum `$anchors` is empty, but that is not the root problem.

Comment: @willum Awesome. Easy, huh? :P